# How to check if selected values are same in different dropdowns with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function validate() {
    var d1 = document.getElementById("edit-submitted-23");
    var d2 = document.getElementById("edit-submitted-24");

    if (d1 == d2) {
      alert("You have choosen the same value");
    }
  }
});
```

I am trying to check if selected values are same in different dropdowns with Javascript. However the code that I use gives no alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the values:

```
if (d1.value === d2.value) {
//... your code here
}
```

Comment: typo from original post: `dd2` -> `d2`

Answer (score 2):

You are checking the elements directly, where you want to check values.

So your condition should be

```
 if (d1.value == d2.value) {

 }
```

Comment: typo from original post: `dd2` -> `d2`

Comment: @FabianN. Good catch.

Comment: I have changed my code but still I dont get any alert on the screen

Comment: @allstar Where you are calling your validate ?

Answer (score 1):

What your code does is compare two DOM references together. This will always give false as you are comparing different *HTML elements*. What you mean to do is to compare the elements’ *values*. Your code should be like this:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
     var d1 = document.getElementById("edit-submitted-23");
     var d2 = document.getElementById("edit-submitted-24");

     if (d1.value == d2.value)
     { 
       alert("You have choosen the same value");
     }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="edit-submitted-23">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>  
</select>

<select id="edit-submitted-24">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>  
</select>
```

I should also note that your code defines a function `validate()` but doesn’t use it. You don’t need to define it. Or if you do, you need to call it afterwards:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   function validate(){
       ....
   }

   validate();
})
```

Comment: I have tried this one but still ı dont get any alert on the screen

Comment: Could you log `d1.value` and `d2.value`? (Use `console.log()`)

Comment: Hi sorry, I forgot to mention that you need to call `validate()`. Check the updates to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help.Now my code works but not dynamics it gives the alert just when I reload the page

http://collabedit.com/anrcj

Comment: Your code runs only when the page loads. If you wish for it to run whenever a menu is updates, you should define your `validate()` method outside of `$(document).ready()`. Then give both `<select>` elements onchange like this: `<select onchange=validate()>`.

Comment: I am calling it on button click

http://collabedit.com/26svw

I dont have to do ıt dynamıc actually ıf ıt gıves the alert after button click it s also ok however after I added button click part in the code it doesnt give alert

Comment: So `onclick` runs everytime you click on the element. The advantage with `onchange` is that it will only call the function if the value is changed. I thought you might want to know that for the future. If you need anything else let me know. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using JQuery, you can do check like this:

```
function validate() {
  if($("#edit-submitted-23").val() === $("#edit-submitted-24").val()) {
    alert('You have choosen the same value');
  }
}
```

Assuming you are calling `validate()` on some event.

Comment: Thanks for your help.Now my code works but not dynamics it gives the alert just when I reload the page 
collabedit.com/anrcj

Comment: It will give `alert()` when you call this function and not when page reloads. When are you calling this function???

Comment: I am calling it on button click

http://collabedit.com/26svw

I dont have to do ıt dynamıc actually ıf ıt gıves the alert after button click it s also ok however after I added button click part in the code it doesnt give alert

Comment: Are you still looking for answers? because you have already accepted another answer.

Comment: yes because after I have added button click,it doesnt give alert anymore